# Can I set up conditional forwarding for a parent DNS zone?

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows

If my domain is ds.usepowershell.com, can I set up a conditional forwarder for usepowershell.com and not redirect my internal queries (since technically, ds.usepowershell.com is a subdomain of usepowershell.com)?

Comment: I may be tired and failing to brain, but I'm a bit unclear on the question here.  Which DNS queries to you want to forward (from which zone to which zone), and which queries do you *not* want to forward?  And, in general, knowing what, specifically you're trying to do (or avoid/fix/workaround) with regards to this question would probably be helpful.

Comment: I'd like to set up a conditional forwarder for the parent domain, but I don't want to interrupt resolution for my internal queries.  Shane's answer below works.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your DNS servers are authoritative for ds.usepowershell.com, that is where their authority ends. Queries for any other domain, including the parent domain, need to be resolved either through the use of forwarders (conditional or otherwise) or through the root hint servers.

So the answer in a nutshell is: Yes you can set up conditional forwarders for usepowershell.com.

Answer (score 4):

It will not forward queries for which there is a local, authoritative zone; the authoritative records will be used to answer instead of using the conditional forwarder.